# setting up windows server 2008 r2 to run asp.net using IIS

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, iis

I have a problem when I try to configure my office's windows server 2008 R2

I got the problem when I want to access my asp.net application using local IP address

First (using local IP Address), I set up my application on IIS to run on port 8080 but when I try to access it using local IP Address, it's showing IIS 7.0 page. It works fine when I'm using localhost to access the website

any help?

Comment: Configure the DNS Server at W2K8 and add the appropriate entries. Check redirection settings in IIS.

Comment: how to that??sorry I've just using W2K8 for 2 days...could please give me any link that cover your suggestion???

Comment: http://forums.iis.net/ /IIS http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/the-enterprise-cloud/how-do-i-install-and-configure-a-dns-server-in-windows-server-2008/327/ DNS http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3HUMTMMAE6Y DNS

Answer (score 0):

You should check your bindings, in IIS Manager it should look something like this:

[image]

With these bindings both localhost:8080 and 192.168.x.xx:8080 should bring up the test site. This has nothing to do with DNS.